# Load RGB images as a ndarray, and plot out with color change

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, plot

I tried to load and plot several images(jpg) from a local folder, and found out the plotting images changed color. The color channel correction between OpenCV and Matplotlib has been done.

How did it happen? How to correct the color?
Thanks.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

folder = 'New_Web_Image'
img_list = np.empty([0,32,32,3])
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, file)) 
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32,32), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    #plt.imshow(img)  
    #plt.show()#If I plot the image here, the image show right color

    img_list = np.append(img_list, [img[:, :, :]], axis=0) 
    print(img_list.shape) #lists shape check right


plt.imshow(img_list[0]) 
plt.show() #If I plor the image from the lists, the color changed
```

Here is the image result in the loop: 
[image: images plot after resize] 
Here is the image from ndarray "lists":
[image: images plot from img_list[0]]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a color correction. OpenCV orders layers as BGR, rather than the RGB we usually expect. As long as you're staying with the OpenCV world, that should be fine. But anding and image loaded via `cv2.imread()` to `matplotlib.pyplot` steps outside that world, which is why you need

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

to get the layers reordered first.

A bunch of other interesting (and possibly useful) conversions are possible. See http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html

Answer (score 0):

To halfly answer my own question, I've corrected the colors by

- loading the images with a ndarray output first,
- and then changing color & size, and plotting the images

Updated code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

# Load the images 
folder = 'New_Web_Image'
img_list = []
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, file)) 
    if img is not None:
        img_list.append(img)
img_list = np.asarray(img_list)    

# Plot the images
n = img_list.shape[0]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, n, figsize=(20,5), dpi=80)
for i in range(n):
    img = img_list[i]
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32,32), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    axs[i].imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Another half question, that "***how did the color change in previous code?***" is still unclear to me.

Thanks in advance to who would suggest.